# How can I fill an horizontal scrollable UITableView with an array that comes from a WS?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, rest, uicollectionview

I've never used an horizontal scrollable Table View before, so I don't know how to fill from a REST API as the way I do it with a vertical scrollable Table View. I found an example here:

'https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/HorizontalScrollingCollectionView'

with hardcoded data, but when I use the data from the WS the Table Cell doesn't show anything.

This is my code (Is the most important Class because is the one that conforms the TableCell, that in this case is a cell that comes inside a CollectionView, and this is where I make the call to the REST API):

```
class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var getUserData = ["clientType" : "2", "docType" : "002","docNum": "16191725","email": "corp.admin@postpago.com","msisdn": "914171620"]
    var purchases : NSArray = []

    struct MobileLines {
        let name:String
        let benefit:String
        let price:String
        let expiration:String

        init?(_ dict:[String:Any]?) {
            guard let _dict = dict,
                let name = _dict["name"] as? String,
                let benefit = _dict["benefit"] as? String,
                let price = _dict["price"] as? String,
                let expiration = _dict["expiration"] as? String
                else { return nil }

            self.name = name
            self.benefit = benefit
            self.price = price
            self.expiration = expiration
        }
    }

    var arrMobileLines = [MobileLines]()

    func getPurchases (_ userData: NSDictionary) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://162.209.99.39:8080/MiClaroBackend/purchase/mobile/MobilePostpaidActive-51914171620/products?type=voice")
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        self.getUserData = userData as! [String : String]
        let paramToSend = ["userData":userData]
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramToSend)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data else
            {
                return
            }

            let json:AnyObject?

            do {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json{
                    let purchaseProducts = parseJSON["purchaseProducts"] as! NSArray
                    self.purchases = purchaseProducts

                    print(json!)
                }
            } catch {

            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrMobileLines.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
        self.arrMobileLines = self.purchases.flatMap({ MobileLines($0 as? [String:Any])})

        let dataAtIndex = self.arrMobileLines[indexPath.row]

        cell.name.text = String(dataAtIndex.name)
        return cell
    }

}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }

}
```

The CollectionViewCell has only a Label:

```
import UIKit

class VideoCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
}
```

At last I have a ViewController where the method that calls the REST API is implemented at the ViewDidLoad():

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"]

    var categoryRow = CategoryRow()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        categoryRow.getPurchases(categoryRow.getUserData as NSDictionary)

    }

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
        return cell
    }

}
```

This is how the storyboard looks like:

[image: Storyboard]

At last this is what the App shows (nothing):

[image: App Simulated]

As you can see at the picture below, the App is returning the WS array correct, so that is not the problem. Another strange thing is that the background of the cell is appearing black when it should be red.

Comment: Try calling `self.collectionView.reloadData()` after you set `self.purchases` in the network request completion.

Comment: Why are you doing the API call inside the view (instead of the controller)? Why are you saving a tableviewcell in the controller as a global variable??

Comment: Because the content of the tableviewcell is inside de API